# Accessing asynchronous activity state in Espresso

Tags: android, android-volley, android-espresso

I want to know how many list items are used in a RecyclerView so I can iterate over the list items and click on them with Espresso. The problem is I'm using Volley asynchronously to get the JSON data I need for the underlying data set of my adapter. I've used an idling resource counter in my UI test to defer the execution of the test until the counter is zero. However, calling the `getItemCount` on my adapter still results in zero, despite the fact that my networking operation should resolve before the test executes.

UI test code

```
@Test
public void foo(){

  // Register a idling resource counter for Volley to get JSON data asynchronously
  Espresso.registerIdlingResources(mActivityTestRule.getActivity().idlingCounter);

  RecyclerView v
          = (RecyclerView)
          mActivityTestRule.getActivity().findViewById(R.id.rv_recycler_view);


  int count = v.getAdapter().getItemCount();

  // Prints zero; why?
  System.out.println("adapter count = "+String.valueOf(count));
}
```

Here is my onCreate method. The adapter list is initialized as empty, but is populated in `onReponse` when Volley finishes networking. However, Espresso doesn't seem to wait for `onReponse` to be called. Not sure why, as I believe I'm using the idling resource counter correctly.

```
RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
public Adapter mAdapter;

public CountingIdlingResource idlingCounter = new CountingIdlingResource("DATA_LOADER");

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstaceState){

    // ... some code

    // Init an empty array list
    ArrayList<MyObject> list = new ArrayList<>();

    // Init the adapter with the list, and set that adapter to the view
    mRecyclerAdapter = new Adapter(List, MainActivity.this);
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mRecyclerAdapter);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(MainActivity.this));

    // Add JSON data to list; increment idlingCounter resource counter.
    // decrement idlingCounter in onResponse
    idlingCounter.increment();
    fetchJson();
}
```

**Edit**

`MainActivity` class

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    // Debugging
    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    // Testing
    public CountingIdlingResource idlingCounter = new CountingIdlingResource("DATA_LOADER");

    // Networking
    private RequestQueue requestQueue;

    // Data
    private ArrayList<Recipe> mRecipes = new ArrayList<>();

    // UI
    public Adapter mRecyclerAdapter;
    @BindView(R.id.rv_recycler_view) RecyclerView mRecyclerView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ButterKnife.bind(this);

        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Recipes");

        // Perform networking if there is no saved instance state
        if(null == savedInstanceState){

            requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
            // TODO calling idlingCounter.increment()
            idlingCounter.increment();
            fetch(requestQueue); // Initializes the recycler view adapter when done fetching

        } else {
            Log.v(TAG,"null != savedInstanceState");
            mRecipes = savedInstanceState.getParcelableArrayList(Constants.KEY_RECIPES);
            mRecyclerAdapter = new Adapter(mRecipes, this);
            mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mRecyclerAdapter);
            mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        outState.putParcelableArrayList(Constants.KEY_RECIPES,mRecipes);
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }

    // Fetch json and build recipe-object array-list
    private void fetch(RequestQueue requestQueue) {

        // Define the request
        JsonArrayRequest request = new JsonArrayRequest(Constants.JsonURL,
                new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {

                    // Handles JSON response data
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray jsonArray) {

                        Log.v(TAG,"onResponse");

                        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                            try {
                                JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                                Recipe recipe = new Recipe(jsonObject);
                                //recipe.mSteps.remove(0);
                                mRecipes.add(recipe);
                                Log.v(TAG,jsonObject.toString());

                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }

                        // Initialize adapter when JSON data is ready
                        // TODO initializing the adapter withe the data set
                        mRecyclerAdapter = new Adapter(mRecipes, MainActivity.this);
                        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mRecyclerAdapter);
                        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(MainActivity.this));

                        // Test if this activity was opened from the widget using an intent
                        Intent intent = getIntent();

                        if(intent.getExtras() != null){

                            // Start TwoPaneActivity passing it the intent extra
                            int position = intent.getIntExtra(WidgetProvider.INTENT_KEY_RECIPE_IDX,-1);
                            intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,TwoPaneActivity.class);
                            Recipe recipe = mRecipes.get(position);
                            intent.putExtra(Constants.KEY_SINGLE_RECIPE,recipe);
                            startActivity(intent);
                        }

                        // TODO calling idlingCounter.decrement()
                        idlingCounter.decrement();
                    }
                },

                // Error listener object
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Unable to fetch data: "
                                + volleyError.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });

        // Queue the request
        requestQueue.add(request);
    }

    public void foo(){

    }
}
```

Comment: once you fetch the json in your fetchJson you should do  `idlingCounter.decrement();`

Comment: Yes, I have done that thanks, has no effect

Comment: I don't want to assert a count, I want to actually know the count.

Comment: ok i ran a sample. It should work fine. My bad i made a mistake in my sample. Your code looks alright and should work fine. Can you post your adapter code and where you update list just in case

Comment: I added the entire class to the post @Raghunandan

Comment: code snippets of my sample that works. https://gitlab.com/users/raghunandan2005/snippets. I used retrofit for n/w calls instead of volley. The rest is similar to yours. The test works